# How do I find out what process is consuming pending signals?

Tags: signals

A user is getting the following message when they try to run a particular program.

> timer_create: Resource temporarily unavailable

From this StackOverflow Q&A titled: [timer_create() : -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179427/timer-create-1-eagain-resource-temporarily-unavailable), I discovered that this has to do with running out of space for pending signals. I confirmed this using a separate user account by running this command:

```
$ ulimit -i 0
```

and checking that I get the same error, which indeed I do.  With this command:

```
$ ulimit -i 1
```

or any higher amount there is no error.

When the original user runs `ulimit -i` they get 127368.  Thus I concluded that they had run out of space for pending signals somehow.

What is going on?  Does it mean that one or more running programs has consumed these? If so how do I find out which ones?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this isn't a **pretty** solution, but at least it might be **a** solution.

In `/proc/[pid]/status` there is an entry for SigPnd and ShdPnd.  They are described as,

> SigPnd, ShdPnd: Number of signals pending for thread and for process
>   as a whole (see pthreads(7) and signal(7)).

There's also SigQ which is,

> SigQ: This field contains two slash-separated numbers that relate to
>   queued signals for the real user ID of this process. The first of
>   these is the number of currently queued signals for this real user ID,
>   and the second is the resource limit on the number of queued signals
>   for this process (see the description of RLIMIT_SIGPENDING in
>   getrlimit(2)).

(All of this is from `man 5 proc`).

So you could search all the pid's in `/proc`, check their `status` files, and find the one with any pending signals.

Try this,

`cd /proc`

`find . -name "status" | xargs grep SigPnd 2> /dev/null | grep -v "0000000000000000"`

and

`find . -name "status" | xargs grep ShdPnd 2> /dev/null | grep -v "0000000000000000"`

Comment: No need to crawl all of `/proc`. Since we're talking about one user here, how about looking for that user's processes and only searching for the `status` file of those? You can get a list of PIDs for processes started by a single user with `ps -u user_name -o pid=`

Comment: That's great, thanks.  Actually I already knew this information was available throught `ps -eo user,pending,command` for example but I didn't know how to interpret it.  I have a command which has ShdPnd of `0000000200000000`.  Do you know what this "bitmap of pending signals" means?  Clearly it's not zero, but I don't know how many it is!

Comment: @JosephR. you could do that, but the time it would have taken me to work out the `ps` command to get the numbers, was longer than the time it took `find` to trawl through the process tree (in my case).

Comment: @EightBitTony Good. I just think it's wise to qualify your `find` whenever possible.

Comment: @TomEllis the text I pasted suggests those aren't signal masks, but counts, however, they would be huge if that was the case so there must be something else going on.

Comment: I think there must be a bug in `man 5 proc` then, because these are definitely not signal counts.  `man 1 ps` makes it very clear they are masks.  However, a couple of lines above is `SigQ:   127368/127368`!  So indeed I can see that the signal count has hit its limit, but unfortunately this is a user-wide count -- it's the same for all this user's processes.  I still can't tell which process in particular is responsible.